# Recursive mergesort in C not modifying the original array

Tags: c, arrays, mergesort

I am implementing merge sort in C. I have a merge function - `merge(int array[], int start, int middle, int end)` and a mergeSort function - `mergeSort(int *array, unsigned int size)`.

The merge sort works perfectly if the first half of the original array and the second half of the original array are sorted (ex: `5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4`). This is because my merge function is getting passed the original array no matter what, and it works when it is given 2 sorted arrays (as expected). My issue is when they aren't. Every time I call merge, my original array isn't being modified, even though I have programmed it to do so. Can anyone figure out where my issue is? The code is below.

When I run this code on input `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}` it returns `{5,4,3,2,1,0,10,9,8,7,6}`.

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) {

    int size1 = m - l + 1;
    int size2 = r - m;

    int arr1[size1];
    int arr2[size2];

    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < size1; i++ ) {
        arr1[i] = arr[l + i];
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < size2; i++ ) {
        arr2[i] = arr[m + i + 1];
    }

    i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while ( i < size1 && j < size2 ) {
        if ( arr1[i] < arr2[j] ) {
            arr[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = arr2[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while ( i < size1 ) {
        arr[k] = arr1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while ( j < size2 ) {
        arr[k] = arr2[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *array, unsigned int size) {
    int start = 0;
    int middle = (size / 2) - 1;
    int end = size - 1;

    if ( size < 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    int m = ( size / 2 );

    int arr1[m];
    int arr2[size - m];

    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < middle + 1; i++ ) {
        arr1[i] = array[i];
        printf("%d\n", arr1[i]);
    }

    for ( i = middle + 1; i < size; i++ ) {
        arr2[i - (middle + 1)] = array[i];
    }

    mergeSort(arr1, m);
    mergeSort(arr2, size - m);
    merge(array, start, middle, end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `mergeSort`, after doing `mergeSort(arr1, m)` and `mergeSort(arr2, size - m)`, you are not actually doing anything with `arr1` and `arr2`.

For a simple fix, I suggest not using the variables `arr1` and `arr2` and calling `mergeSort` directly on parts of `array`, like so:

```c
void mergeSort(int* array, unsigned int size) {
    int start = 0;
    int middle = (size / 2);
    int end = size - 1;

    if ( size < 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    mergeSort(array, middle);
    mergeSort(array + middle, size - middle);
    merge(array, start, middle - 1, end);
}
```

Comment: Is this all of the code?  I know that recursion can make for very elegant algorithms, but this one seems unrealistically terse.  Seems like you're not actually doing anything with `array`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, there's the whole `merge` function part (for which OP gave a correct implementation). Together with that, it is working code (although it might have issues with really big arrays because OP is using `int` instead of `size_t` for sizes).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- the `mergeSort` function splits the array into 2 local arrays and calls itself recursively to sort them, but the `merge` phase does not take these sorted arrays as inputs. You should instead use portions of the argument array directly.
- the size computations are cumbersome, with many adjustments that would pose problems for small values of `size`. Use a simple convention: pass `end` as the offset of the first element past the end of the array. This way the size is computing simply by subtracting `start` from `end`.
- the `merge` function initializes `k` to `0` instead of `l`.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
void merge(int arr[], int start, int m, int end) {
    int size1 = m - start;
    int size2 = end - m;
    int arr1[size1];
    int arr2[size2];
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        arr1[i] = arr[start + i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        arr2[i] = arr[m + i];
    }

    i = j = 0;
    k = start;

    while (i < size1 && j < size2) {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
            arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < size1) {
        arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
    }
    while (j < size2) {
        arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *array, unsigned int size) {
    if (size >= 2) {
        int m = size / 2;
        mergeSort(array, m);
        mergeSort(array + m, size - m);
        merge(array, 0, m, size);
}
```

*Bob__* suggested a simplification, saving only the first half of the array to `arr1` and removing the need for `arr2`. Here is a modified version, also removing `start` which is always `0` and some other simplifications:

```c
void merge(int arr[], size_t m, size_t size) {
    int arr1[m];
    size_t i, j, k;

    for (i = j = k = 0; j < m; j++) {
        arr1[j] = arr[j];
    }

    while (i < m && j < size) {
        if (arr1[i] < arr[j]) {
            arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < m) {
        arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *array, size_t size) {
    if (size >= 2) {
        size_t m = size / 2;
        mergeSort(array, m);
        mergeSort(array + m, size - m);
        merge(array, m, size);
}
```

Note however that allocating `arr1` with automatic storage, aka *on the stack*, may cause undefined behavior for large arrays, typically larger than a few hundreds of thousand of elements. Allocating a temporary array from the heap avoid this problem at the cost of extra overhead and the possibility for allocation failure.

Comment: It may be more obscure or less "symmetric", but there's no need to use `arr2` and copy the second half, those element can be safely moved in the right position, when needed.

Comment: @Bob__ Indeed `arr2` could be dropped, but the computation of `m` must be adjusted to ensure that `size1 >= size2` otherwise some pathological distributions will be corrupted. `int m = (size + 1) / 2;` does the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure that `size1` must be greater then `size2`. Let's call those *p* and *q*. We enforce *p* <= *q* <= *p* + 1 to gain logarithmic complexity, but *p* could be smaller, even 1 (it would be like bubble sort). When first *p* (sorted) elements are copied, the same amount of space is freed. If an element of the second half is moved into its correct position, the total number of available positions remains constant (the actual value of *p*). The free space is reduced (and so the number of elements *p* still to be copied) only when one of the other ones is moved back. BTW a `}` is missing.

Comment: @Bob__: Indeed you're right, I don't know where I got this idea, it does not even matter how `size` is split. Both `size / 2` and `(size + 1) / 2` produce the same number of recursive calls but `merge` would work for any proportion, although other proportions would decrease overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted merge on every recursive is done on local array created on stack and it is not carry forwarded to previous function call. End result of entire recursive call is nothing but merge of `{10,9,8,7,6}` and `{5,4,3,2,1}`.

You can find the debug verification [here](https://onlinegdb.com/H1wXjNtMU).

**Note:**   output has variation in my debug code as caller of mergeSort can have different implementation

Updated snippet as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) {

    int size1 = m - l;
    int size2 = r - m;

    int arr1[size1];
    int arr2[size2];

    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
        arr1[i] = arr[l + i];
    }

    for ( i = 0; i+m < r; i++ ) {
        arr2[i] = arr[m + i ];
    }

    i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while ( i < size1 && j < size2 ) {
        if ( arr1[i] < arr2[j] ) {
            arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
            }
    }
    while ( i < size1 ) {
        arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
    }
    while ( j < size2 ) {
        arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int* array, unsigned int size) {

    if ( size < 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    int start = 0;
    int middle = (size / 2);
    int end = size;

    mergeSort(array, middle);
    mergeSort(&array[middle], end-middle);
    merge(array, start, middle, end);
}


int main()
{
    int a[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    const int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    mergeSort(a,size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
       printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

> output : `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`